# Cron job using apache camel (plus ldap server)

Tags: javascript, cron, ldap, apache-camel

I have created one cron job
from("quartz://myscheduler?cron=20+*+*+*+*+?").bean(LdapBean.class, "start"); (interval time=20s)

Now from "start" method I want to make call to ldap server to fetch data of specific user. from("direct:start").to("ldap:ldapserver?base=ou=group,dc=dc1,dc=dc2").to("bean:ldapBean");

This was my previous call without cron job.

How can I do that without creating multiple routes. (route is created each time the method calls).
Also I am getting TestDao null in method

public void process(Exchange exchange) {}

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just do

```
from quartz
  to ldap
  bean
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But from quartz I won't get any data, I need to fetch users of specific group from ldap server at regular interval, I was again creating camelContext which is not proper way I think. Also the data I set in start method, I am not getting in process method. What should I do?

Comment: See about pojo producing so you can call a camel route from a java bean - https://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html

Comment: Also you may want to read the free chapter4 of the Camel book that goes in depth of using beans with Camel - http://manning.com/ibsen2/

Comment: Thank you. I will refer the links.